# Using Python Re to extract percentages from string

Tags: regex, python-re

I've been trying to build a python script to download torrent files using `transmission cli` and I need to print the download progress and abort the script once the download is finished.

So I tried using regex as mentioned in the code block below

```
out = subprocess.check_output("transmission-remote --auth 'transmission':'transmission' --list", shell=True);
percentage = re.findall(r'^[0-9].+%$', str(out))
print(percentage)
```

But so far it's returning an empty list and the value of `out` is as below

```
ID     Done       Have  ETA           Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name
   1   100%    5.57 GB  Done        71.0     1.0    0.0  Seeding      Sample
Sum:           5.57 GB              71.0     1.0
```

Why's the regex not extracting the percentages?
Some help is appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use the beginning and end of line anchors (`^` and `$`, respectively) if you are matching a pattern in the middle of the line.

Comment: Do you need to support float values in the percentage, e.g. `34.12%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

`(\d{1,3})%`

The capture group grabs only the digits (that are immediately followed by a percentage `%` char).

Comment: So the problem with my code was that I was using the beginning and end of line anchors?

Comment: I believe so, have you tried the pattern in my answer?

Comment: I just noticed `(\d{1,3})%` returns let's say 37 but removing the parenthesis returns 37%. Why is that?

Comment: The parentheses form a [capture group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group), meaning that the entire pattern will be matched, but only the portion of the pattern between the parentheses will be captured in that group. So in this case only the digits (and not the `%`) are captured.